# Estimate for sum over zeros of Riemann zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

The Riemann-von Mangoldt formula for the number of non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ with imaginary part between $0$ and $T$ is given by
$$
N(T) = \#\{\rho = \beta + i\gamma \in \mathbb{C} : \zeta(\rho) = 0 \text{ and } 0 < \beta < 1,  0 \leq \gamma \leq 
 T\} = \frac{T}{2\pi} \log \frac{T}{2 \pi} - \frac{T}{2 \pi} + O(\log T).  \label{riemann mangoldt formula} \tag{1}
$$

From Davenport's book, I know that
\begin{equation} 
\sum_{\gamma} \frac{1}{1 + (t - \gamma)^2} = O(\log t), \label{my eqn} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $\gamma$  runs over the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$. I want to obtain an estimate for the sum
$$
\sum_{\gamma \not\in [0, T]} \frac{1}{1 + (t - \gamma)^2}
$$
when $t \in [0, T]$ using \eqref{riemann mangoldt formula} and \eqref{my eqn}. I tried using a modified version of Abel's summation to obtain
$$
\sum_{\gamma > T} \frac{1}{1 + (t - \gamma)^2} = - \frac{N(T)}{1 + (t - T)^2} - 2 \int_{T}^{\infty} \frac{N(x)(t-x)}{(1 + (t-x)^2)^2}\, dx
$$
and
$$
\sum_{\gamma < 0} \frac{1}{1 + (t - \gamma)^2} = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{N(x)(t + x)}{(1 + (t + x)^2)^2} \, dx,
$$
but I seem to not being able to cleverly solve or manipulate the integral to get estimate of the form
$$
\sum_{\gamma \not\in [0, T]} \frac{1}{1 + (t - \gamma)^2} \ll \left( \frac{1}{t+1} + \frac{1}{T-t+1} \right) \log T
$$
for $t \in [0, T]$. Any hint or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the only thing to know is that $N(T+1)-N(T)=O(\log T)$ and then estimating the zeroes with $\gamma \in [T+n, T+n+1]$ by $O(\log (T+n)=O(\log T), n \le T, O(\log n), n \ge T$ and $\gamma-t \ge T+n-t$ for them will do and give you the $\frac{\log T}{T-t+1}$ bound - not sure why you need the other term unless you include zeroes with negative $\gamma$

Comment: Thanks Conrad. But I still do not understand how can one get the putative bound from the series $\sum_{n \leq T} \frac{O(\log T)}{1 + (T + n -t)^2} + \sum_{n > T} \frac{O(\log n)}{1 + (T + n - t)^2}$. Pardon me if I am overlooking something trivial here.

Comment: the first guy is $O(\log T)\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{1}{1+(n-x)^2}, x=T-t$ which by the integral test is clearly $O(\frac{\log T}{x}), x \ge 1$ and $O(\log T), 0 \le x \le 1$ which can be put together as $O(\frac{\log T}{T-t+1})$ keeping in mind that $x=T-t$; the second guy is $<< \sum_{ n\ge T}\frac{\log n}{n^2}$ which again by the integral test is $O(\log T/T)$ so smaller

Comment: I also got there in a round about way but yours is very crystal clear.

Comment: happy to be of help